# LINQ - Fetch items from list starting from specific index

Tags: c#, linq

With the help of LINQ, I need to fetch items from a list based on a condition. For that it should consider items only from `(provided index - 3)` to provided index (dynamically).

For example, a list contains items `{1,3,5,7,9,11,13}`. If provided index is 4, the it should consider total three indexes starting from index 2 to ending at index 4. Among these three items, it should be filter them with a condition - say, Item should be greater than 5.

The result should be - `{7,9}`

What I tried is, which is wrong and I am stuck:

```
list.Select(item => list.Select(index => item[index - 3] && item > 5).ToList());
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a mix of [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx), filtering with [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query = list.Skip(index - 3)    // Start at appropriate index
                .Take(3)            // Only consider the next three values
                .Where(x => x > 5); // Filter appropriately
```

Personally it seems a little odd to me that the index would be the *end* point rather than the *start* point, mind you. You might want to see if other pieces of code would benefit from changing that.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `Skip` and `Take` would be to include the item index in the `Where` clause

```
list.Where((x, i) => // x is the list item, i is its index
    i > (index - 3) && i <= index && // index bounds
    x > 5 // item condition
)
```

For you specific requirement with a single sub-range of items, I'd go with the `Skip` and `Take`, but if you ever need a more complex condition on the item index, you can utilize this `Where` overload.